# The difference between NonFatal and Exception in Scala

Tags: scala, exception

In [this article](https://tersesystems.com/2012/12/27/error-handling-in-scala/), it's said that:

> If you want to catch “everything” that would normally happen, then use
>   NonFatal:

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

try {
  operation()
} catch {
  case NonFatal(e) => errorHandler(e)
}
```

But I usually use `Exception`:

```
try {
  operation()
} catch {
  case e: Exception => errorHandler(e)
}
```

I would like to know what is the difference between `NonFatal` and `Exception` in Scala? Does `Exception` in Scala include fatal exception?

AFAIK in java, `Exception` is for non-fatal error and `Error` is for fatal error. Is scala different with java in term of `Exception`?

Which way is the correct one to catch non-fatal exception?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Edit:** updated for the latest Scala version (2.11+ has a different definition of `NonFatal.apply`).

---

`NonFatal` is just a convenient extractor which is defined in `scala.util.control`:

```scala
object NonFatal {
   /**
    * Returns true if the provided `Throwable` is to be considered non-fatal, or false if it is to be considered fatal
    */
   def apply(t: Throwable): Boolean = t match {
     // VirtualMachineError includes OutOfMemoryError and other fatal errors
     case _: VirtualMachineError | _: ThreadDeath | _: InterruptedException | _: LinkageError | _: ControlThrowable => false
     case _ => true
   }
  /**
   * Returns Some(t) if NonFatal(t) == true, otherwise None
   */
  def unapply(t: Throwable): Option[Throwable] = if (apply(t)) Some(t) else None
}
```

There is no special "fatal" kind of exceptions on JVM - `Error`s are not always "fatal", they're just a special kind of internal exceptions. "Fatal" exceptions are just a list of exceptions used in `NonFatal` definition. In this terminology all `Exception`s except `InterruptedException` are considered non-fatal. It makes sense to consider `InterruptedException` fatal because it means that the thread is interrupted, so if you want to handle it you should do it explicitly.

`NonFatal` extractor also handles `ControlThrowable`s correctly. These are exceptions which are thrown by special control transfer functions like `break` inside `breakable`.

Comment: I'm not still really clear, so `NonFatal` and `Exception` is roughly same?

Comment: No. When you match on `e: Exception` you are inspecting the actual type of the exception, much like `catch (Exception e)` in Java. If the exception is a subclass of `Exception`, the exception will be caught. `NonFatal`, on the other hand, is an extractor object which performs additional logic on the matched value. In this case `NonFatal(e)` will match (and catch the exception) only when `NonFatal.apply(e)` returns `true`. When it returns `true` you can see in the piece of code above.

Comment: You should read some tutorial on extractors, like [this](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html) one, if you don't know what they are.

Comment: So `case e: Exception` would also include `VirtualMachineError, ThreadDeath, LinkageError, ControlThrowable, NotImplementedError`? Do you also suggest `case NonFatal(e)` should be used instead of `case e: Exception` in most of case?

Comment: No, `case e: Exception` won't include `VirtualMachineError` and such because those are `Error`s, not `Exception`s. And yes, I suggest using `NonFatal` because it is more convenient in most cases (due to proper handling of `InterruptedException` or `ControlThrowable`, for example).

Comment: What's the situation of `InterruptedException` would occur? For the code inside block of `Future{ .. } `, is it possible for it to throw `InterruptedException`?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty much possible but is very unlikely as `InterruptedException` is more likely to be thrown with low-level threading code. You can usually find when an exception is used/throw in [their API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).

Comment: `ControlThrowable` is a `Throwable`, not an `Exception`, and as such won't be caught by `case e: Exception`; `case NonFatal(e)` won't differ in its handling there.

Comment: why is StackOverflow NonFatal?

Comment: @dangonfast That was changed in Scala 2.11 (and 2.12); `StackOverflow` is fatal. See [NonFatal docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/#scala.util.control.NonFatal$). Also more info in the [issue tracker](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7999) and the [fixing pull request and google groups discussion](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3182)

Answer (score 6):

Exceptions don't get mentioned very much in Scala, but they're still what is done multiple times when dealing with unexpected failure.

When we look for ***When to catch java.lang.Error?*** multiple answers, and opinions will be present, but let's focus on the common part.

**A reasonable application should not try to catch**

- "An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch."
- "Thrown to indicate that the Java Virtual Machine is broken or has run out of resources necessary for it to continue operating."
- "Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector."

`NonFatal` is an Extractor of non-fatal Throwables. Will not match fatal errors like `VirtualMachineError` (for example, `OutOfMemoryError` and `StackOverflowError`, subclasses of `VirtualMachineError`), `ThreadDeath`, `LinkageError`, `InterruptedException`, `ControlThrowable`, that are part of the failures a reasonable application should'nt try to catch.

With this in mind, we could write code that catches all harmless Throwables can be caught by:

```scala
try {
  // dangerous code
} catch {
  case NonFatal(e) => log.error(e, "Something not that bad.")
}
```

If we look at the apply method we can see it very clearly.

```scala
object NonFatal {
   /**
    * Returns true if the provided `Throwable` is to be considered non-fatal, or false if it is to be considered fatal
    */
   def apply(t: Throwable): Boolean = t match {
     // VirtualMachineError includes OutOfMemoryError and other fatal errors
     case _: VirtualMachineError | _: ThreadDeath | _: InterruptedException | _: LinkageError | _: ControlThrowable => false
     case _ => true
   }
}
```