# Handling Child Actor Exceptions in Akka

Tags: akka

I have a Supervisor Actor that creates child actors like this:

```
class SupervisorActor extends Actor {

  val child  = context.actorOf(MyConnectorActor.props(config),"MyConnector")

  def receive = {
    case Message => child ! "throw"
  }
}

class MyConnectorActor extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "throw" => throw new Exception()
  }
}
```

Now in my MyConnectorActor child, I throw an exception voluntarily. How should the SupervisorActor handle this? Do I need to add the supervisor strategy?

```
  override val supervisorStrategy =
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 30, withinTimeRange = 1.minute) {
      case _ =>
        println("RESTARTING CHILD FROM SUPERVISOR")
        Restart
    }
```

Even after adding this, I cannot see my child actor restarting? Any ideas as to what else needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a normal exception throw (`throw new ...Exception`) in place of the `???` as it's doing much more harm than a normal Exception does.

The `???` method defined in `Predef` [actually throws an `Error`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L225%20it) (sic!), an NotImplementedError  to be precise. And Errors are not handled by the [`NonFatal()` extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744462/the-difference-between-nonfatal-and-exception-in-scala) that Akka uses in the exception handling code. This is because Errors are deemed as "the system MUST now STOP, ASAP", and not just an "Exception".

Replace the `???` with something more realistic, like a RuntimeException and you should see the Actor be restarted as expected.

Comment: The exception is actually thrown in the child and I want this supervisor to react to that exception and Restart the child. I edited my post! Please take a look!

Comment: It around be restarting in any case since that's the default behavior. Your code should override the supervisionStrategy in the parent with OneForOneStrategy, not just have the one for one defined somewhere. Read up on details in the akka docs

Comment: How are you observing the lack of restart if I may ask?

Comment: I have a preRestart in my child and I see it is never being called!

Comment: Ok it was my mistake! There was a stale jar file and I cleared it up with sbt clean and then re-ran my application and I can see that the child is restarted. But how do I make it do the initialization that it did when started originally before the exception?

Comment: How could I do the initialization? I'm doing the initialization using the postRestart method. Is this the preferred way?

Comment: Yeah, the lifecycle hooks are the right spot to do things like init.