# Weird failure of Scala's type-check

Tags: scala, typechecking, scala-generics

My application dictates need of an *argument provider* `trait` that can be added to any `class` to allow passing of **arbitrary number of arguments of *any* type** with it.

```
trait Arg
case class NamedArg(key: String, value: Any) extends Arg

// I extend my classes with this trait
trait ArgsProvider {
  val args: Seq[Arg]

  lazy val namedArgs: Map[String, Any] = {
    args.filter(_.isInstanceOf[NamedArg]).
      map(_.asInstanceOf[NamedArg]).
      map(arg => arg.key -> arg.value).toMap
  }

  ...
}
```

Then I can extract the `NamedArg`s from `args` of `ArgsProvider` using their `key` as follows

```
trait ArgsProvider {
  ...

  /*
   * Method that takes in a [T: ClassTag] and a (key: String) argument
   * (i) if key exists in namedArgs: Map[String, Any]
   *     - Returns Some(value: T) if value can be casted into T type
   *     - Throws Exception if value can't be casted into T type
   * (ii) if key doesn't exist in namedArgs
   *    Returns None
   */
  def getOptionalTypedArg[T: ClassTag](key: String): Option[T] = {
    namedArgs.get(key).map { arg: Any =>
      try {
        arg.asInstanceOf[T]
      } catch {
        case _: Throwable => throw new Exception(key)
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Even though it may seem *highly unintuitive* and *verbose*, this design works *flawlessly* for me. However, while writing certain `unit tests`, I recently discovered a *major loophole* in it: **it fails to perform `type-checking`**. (or at least that's what I infer)

---

To be more specific, it **doesn't throw any exception** when I try to `type-cast` the provided `arg` into *wrong type*. For example:

```
// here (args: Seq[NamedArg]) overrides the (args: Seq[Arg]) member of ArgsProvider
case class DummyArgsProvider(args: Seq[NamedArg]) extends ArgsProvider

// instantiate a new DummyArgsProvider with a single NamedArg having a String payload (value)
val dummyArgsProvider: DummyArgsProvider = DummyArgsProvider(Seq(
    NamedArg("key-string-arg", "value-string-arg")
))

// try to read the String-valued argument as Long
val optLong: Option[Long] = dummyArgsProvider.getOptionalTypedArg[Long]("key-string-arg")
```

While one would expect the above piece of code to `throw` an `Exception`; to my dismay, it works perfectly fine and returns the following output (on `Scala` `REPL`)

> optLong: Option[Long] = Some(value-string-arg)

---

My questions are:

- Why is type-check failing here?
- Under what circumstances does Scala's type-checking fail, in general?
- Can this design be improved?

---

I'm using

- `Scala 2.11.11`
- `SBT 1.0.3`

Comment: you should try to find a simplified example. This is really long to read. Also, by trying the narrow the problem, you might simply find the error yourself

Comment: Thanks **@Juh_**, I'll try to come up with a *simpler example* and, in due course, narrow down the problem. In the meantime, I would appreciate if you could tell me **whether you are able to reproduce the problem** (just *copy-paste* the given code in `Scala REPL`). I can confirm that even outside my `IntelliJ` project, I'm able to replicate this behaviour on `Scala 2.12.4 REPL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AlexeyRomanov has remarked, `as/isInstanceOf[T]` don't use a `ClassTag`.

You can use pattern matching instead, which does check with a `ClassTag`, if there's one available:

```
trait ArgsProvider {
  /* ... */

  def getOptionalTypedArg[T: ClassTag](key: String): Option[T] = {
    namedArgs.get(key).map {
      case arg: T => arg
      case _ => throw new Exception(key)
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use methods of `ClassTag` directly:

```
import scala.reflect.classTag

def getOptionalTypedArg[T: ClassTag](key: String): Option[T] = {
  namedArgs.get(key).map { arg =>
    classTag[T].unapply(arg).getOrElse(throw new Exception(key))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having problem with type-erasure: The `Option[Long]` actually store the String "value-string-arg" and doesn't care about its type which as been erased.

However, if you do `optLong.get` it will then try to cast it to a Long which is the expected output. And you'll get the ClassCastException

---

Just a  little comments:

replace

```
val namedArgs: Map[String, Any] = {...}
```

by

```
val namedArgs: Map[String, Any] = args.collect{
  case NameArg(k, v) => k -> v
}(collection.breakout)
```

Also, in  your getOptionalTypedArg, don't catch all Throwable. It is bad practice (you could catch OutOfMemoryError and other Fatal errors, which you should not). In your case, you want to catch a ClassCastException. In other case where you don't know exactly which Throwable, try using [NonFatal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29744462/1206998)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs **@Juh_**. I can see that due to `type-erasure`, an `Option[Long]` can refer to `Some(String)`. But don't you think `arg.asInstanceOf[T]` should be able to withstand `erasure` [since it's an **explicit type-cast** analogous to `Java`'s `NewType objOfNewType = (NewType) objOfOldType;`]? Correct me if I'm wrong, but if `erasure` can downplay (manual) `type-casting` then wouldn't `[T: ClassTag]` be rendered pretty-much useless? (which, of course, isn't true; `ClassTag` comes from `scala.reflect` package)

Comment: `as/isInstanceOf[T]` don't use a `ClassTag` even if one is available. To cast it you need to work with `ClassTag`'s methods explicitly. It _is_ exactly analogous to `(NewType) objOfOldType`: `(T) objOfOldType` behaves the same and for the same reason.

Comment: I don't fully understand it either, but asInstanceOf[T] cannot be executed due to type-erasure. Thus, the cast is done when the output of getOptionalTypedArg is accessed. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690611/1206998