# Figure out a way to convert a var implementation to val

Tags: scala, functional-programming, var

I'm using the following interface from a Java library:

```
// This is a Java class from a library I'm using
public interface Listener {
  void receiveConfigInfo(final String configInfo);
}
```

And I'm extending it as follows, in Scala:

```
//MyClass needs to extends the Listener interface
final class MyClass extends Listener {
  private var config = Option.empty

  // Implement the the Listener interface
  override def receiveConfigInfo(configInfo: String): Unit = {
    try {
      config  = decode[Map[String, String]](configInfo) match {
        case Right(config) => Some(config)
        case Left(_) => None
      }
    } catch {
      case _: Throwable => nacosConfig = None
    }
  }

  override def getConfig():Option[Map[String, String]] = nacosConfig
}
```

`receiveConfigInfo` will be called in automatically whenever relevant.

`getConfig` returns the latest value of configuration.

Is there a way to make `config` into a `val`, rather than a mutable `var`? I cannot change the signature of `receiveConfigInfo`, as it needs to respect the signature of parent class.

The objective is whenever I call `getConfig`, I should get latest config value. However my current implementation has a `var` which is not good, is there any way to change this code to make it val or another way if possible?

Comment: There is no _(simple)_ way to remove `var` there. Well, you may use [**Deferred** ](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/cats/effect/concurrent/Deferred.html) from `cats-effect`, but that will change a lot the gay to use your code. I would rather focus on removing the `try` for a [**Try**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) and that `None[Map[String, String]]` is not valid syntax and it is not necessary.

Comment: The Class needs to implement the interface not extend.

Comment: @RajaShekar The example unfortunately mixes Java and Scala together, but in Scala you use `extend` for anything, including Java interfaces (as long as they are the first thing you extend, the keyword `with` must be used for following traits and interfaces).

Comment: Side note: don't catch `Throwable`s, I'd recomment using the `NonFatal` extractor instead (more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744462/the-difference-between-nonfatal-and-exception-in-scala).

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Java interface you're implementing seems to require an implementation to accept arbitrarily many new `configInfo`s, I'd suggest that the most honest thing is to leave the var but encapsulated such that it can only be changed via `receiveConfigInfo`.

So perhaps something like

```
object MyClass {
  private[MyClass] Config {
    private var underlying: Map[String, String] = Map.empty

    override def get(key: String): Option[String] = 
      synchronized { underlying.get(key) }

    override def toMap: Map[String, String] =
      synchronized { underlying }

    override def update(configInfo: String): Unit =
      synchronized {
        // I'm assuming that decode is somewhere statically accessible
        // I'm also assuming that a function returning an `Either` won't throw non-fatal exceptions... if it can return a Left, a Right, or throw, then:
        //   Try { decode[...](configInfo) }.flatMap(_.left.map(msg => new RuntimeException(msg)).toTry)
        val decoded =
          decode[Map[String, String]](configInfo)
            .left
            .map(_ => new RuntimeException("decode failed")
            .toTry
        decoded.foreach { newConfig => underlying = newConfig }
        decoded.recoverWith { _ =>
          underlying = Map.empty
          decoded
        }
      }
  }
}

class MyClass extends Listener {
  private val config = new MyClass.Config

  override def receiveConfigInfo(configInfo: String): Unit = config.update(configInfo)
}
```

With a solution along these lines, the configuration is immutable to anything in `MyClass` that doesn't call `update` (which is hopefully apparent enough vs. assigning to a `var`.

I'm preserving the behavior of unsetting the config if a bad `configInfo` comes along; it may make more sense to leave `configInfo` unchanged in that case, which would make it even more difficult in practice to inadvertently change the config except by a client of `MyClass` calling `receiveConfigInfo` with a valid config.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a `val`, you can use one of the mutable structures in [collection.mutable](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.10/scala/collection/mutable/index.html). However, it would be more roundabout, possibly prone to error, and behind the scenes, actually using `var`, so you might as well directly use `var` (the way your code already is).

```scala
// in class structure
val config = collection.mutable.IndexedSeq[Option[Map[String, String]]](None)
...
// in receiveConfigInfo
config(0) = decode ...

// in getConfig
config(0)
```