# Can Scala try-catch-finally expression be without braces?

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala and confused about the `try-catch-finally` syntax.

In [Scala Syntax Specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/13-syntax-summary.html), it says:

```
Expr1             ::=  ‘try’ Expr [‘catch’ Expr] [‘finally’ Expr]
                     | ...
```

Can I write expression without `{` `}` blocks like this:

```
try
  println("Hello")
catch
  RuntimeException e => println("" + e)
finally
  println("World")
```

Or the expression must be a block expression ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. Why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: I wonder what's the motivation behind the questions, where it takes more time to ask them than just run in the console...

Comment: First-person experimentation is the best way to learn, but I assume the OP is a bit confused by Scala's syntax (which is why the `catch` expression is not valid in the post) and couldn't understand the compiler error enough to make sense of it.

Comment: Downvoting because this can be trivially tried out

Answer (score 5):

Scala 3 (Dotty) is experimenting with [optional braces](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/indentation.html) (significant indentation) so the following works

```
scala> try
     |   1 / 0
     | catch
     |   case e => println(s"good catch $e")
     | finally
     |   println("Celebration dance :)")
     |
good catch java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Celebration dance :)
val res1: AnyVal = ()
```

where we note the handler

```
case e => println(s"good catch $e")
```

did not need braces as in [Scala 2](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#try-expressions). In fact due to [special treatment of `case` clauses](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/indentation.html#special-treatment-of-case-clauses) after `catch` keyword the following would also work

```
scala> try
     |   1 / 0
     | catch
     | case e => println(s"good catch $e")
     | finally
     |   println("Celebration dance :)")
     |
good catch java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Celebration dance :)
val res2: AnyVal = ()
```

where we note the handler did not have to be indented after `catch`

```
catch
case e => println(s"good catch $e")
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

def fourtyseven: PartialFunction[Throwable, Int] = {
  case NonFatal(_) => 47
}

def attempt(n: => Int): Int =
  try n catch fourtyseven finally println("done")

println(attempt(42))
println(attempt(sys.error("welp")))
```

This compiles and runs as expected, although I had to define the `catch` expression separately (as it requires braces).

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/4hpYn7BlQp2dqmhac32b0A/2).

A few of notes:

- `try`/`catch`/`finally` is an expression that returns a value (this could be a bit unfamiliar if you're coming from Java) -- you can read more about it [here on the docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/try-catch-finally.html)
- `catch` always takes a `PartialFunction` from a `Throwable` to some type, with the overall return type of the `try`/`catch` to be the closest common superclass of the two (e.g. say you have `class Animal; class Dog extends Animal; class Cat extends Animal`, if the `try` returns a `Dog` and the `catch` returns a `Cat` the overall expression will return an `Animal`)
- I used the `NonFatal` extractor in the `catch` partial function, you can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744462/the-difference-between-nonfatal-and-exception-in-scala), while extractor objects in general are described [here in the official docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html)